# Oracle - complex update

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

I have two tables which will store the same keys in ID column:

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTA" 
   (    "RECORD_STATUS" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), 
    "ID" NUMBER, --this is PK
    "BATCH" NUMBER
   );
CREATE TABLE "TESTB" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, --this is unique FK to TESTA.ID
    "BATCH" NUMBER);
```

I inserted some 20 test records in these test tables.

Requirement: Join the two tables using `ID`, sort using `TESTA.RECORD_STATUS DESC`, and then update `BATCH` column with increment by 1 (starting from 0) every 5 rows.

This is what I have so far:

```
MERGE INTO TESTB st
USING(SELECT A.rowid as rid, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.RECORD_STATUS DESC) as rn 
      FROM TESTA A) t
ON(st.ROWID=t.RID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET st.BATCH=CEIL(t.rn/5);
```

Issue: Output says 0 rows merged, but I am expecting all rows to to updated.

I would greatly appreciate some insight on how to achieve the expected. I hope I have not missed anything.

Comment: The ROWID is a unique address for each record. You wouldn't expect the ROWID from a row in one table to match any ROWID from any other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `update`:

```
update testb
    set b.batch = (select trunc((seqnum - 1) / 5)
                   from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by a.record_status desc) as seqnum
                         from testa
                        ) a
                   where a.id = testb.id and
                  )
    where exists (select 1 from testa a where a.id = testb.id);
```

Comment: @user3224907 . . . I think so.  Anything you can do with `update` you should be able to do with `merge`.